# How do I extract only the KEYS from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

How do I extract **only** the time range `KEYS` within an array of objects?

The following is my code:

```
console.log(tempRemovedTimeRanges);

const removedKeys = tempRemovedTimeRanges
  .flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj))
  .filter(dayArray => dayArray.some(dayObj => Object.keys(dayObj)[0] === elementToInsert))
  .flatMap(dayArray =>
    dayArray
      .filter(dayObj => Object.keys(dayObj)[0] === elementToInsert)
      .flatMap(dayObj => dayObj[elementToInsert].flatMap(range => Object.keys(range)))
  );

console.log(removedKeys);
```

The code above logs out:

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[]
```

As you can see the `console.log(removedKeys);` code logs out an empty array.

Allow me to expand `tempRemovedTimeRanges` array for you to get an idea of the `tempRemovedTimeRanges` structure:

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   0: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
   1: {Fridays: Array(2)}
   2: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
   3: {Fridays: Array(2)}
   4: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
   5: {Fridays: Array(2)}
   6: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
   7: {Fridays: Array(2)}

[]
```

As you can see, the `tempRemovedTimeRanges` reveals an array of objects representing `days`.

Allow me to expand the first object `0: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}` further.
Kindly note that all objects share a similar structure as the first object `0: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}`

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: 
   Wednesdays: Array(2)
      0: {T_04:00_Start: 1703034000, T_08:00_End: 1703048400}
      1: {T_04:00_Start: 1703638800, T_08:00_End: 1703653200}
  1: {Fridays: Array(2)}
  2: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
  3: {Fridays: Array(2)}
  4: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
  5: {Fridays: Array(2)}
  6: {Wednesdays: Array(2)}
  7: {Fridays: Array(2)}
```

The following section represents two time ranges for the `Wednesdays` object.
The first one is `T_04:00_Start` to `T_08:00_End` and `T_04:00_Start` to `T_08:00_End`

```
{T_04:00_Start: 1703034000, T_08:00_End: 1703048400}
{T_04:00_Start: 1703638800, T_08:00_End: 1703653200}
```

The keys `T_04:00_Start`, `T_08:00_End`, `T_04:00_Start` and  `T_08:00_End` and **NOT** the values (timestamps) are what I am **interesting in capturing** for each day in the `tempRemovedTimeRanges` array

Now going back to my code:

```
console.log(tempRemovedTimeRanges);

const removedKeys = tempRemovedTimeRanges
  .flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj))
  .filter(dayArray => dayArray.some(dayObj => Object.keys(dayObj)[0] === elementToInsert))
  .flatMap(dayArray =>
    dayArray
      .filter(dayObj => Object.keys(dayObj)[0] === elementToInsert)
      .flatMap(dayObj => dayObj[elementToInsert].flatMap(range => Object.keys(range)))
  );

console.log(removedKeys);
```

The desired output of `console.log(removedKeys);` are all the **time ranges** `keys` for each day found in the `tempRemovedTimeRanges`. Those would therefore look like this:

```
[T_04:00_Start, 
T_08:00_End, 
T_04:00_Start, 
T_08:00_End, 
T_12:00_Start, 
T_16:00_End, 
T_12:00_Start, 
T_16:00_End, 
T_20:00_Start, 
T_00:00_End, 
T_20:00_Start, 
T_00:00_End, 
T_16:00_Start, 
T_20:00_End, 
T_16:00_Start, 
T_20:00_End]
```

How do I modify my code to do this?

Comment: Can you share minimum sample of your array and output result you want in JSON?

Comment: what is elementToInsert  maybe `tempRemovedTimeRanges.flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj)).flat().flatMap(obj => Object.keys(obj))`

Comment: or shortened `tempRemovedTimeRanges.flatMap(Object.values).flat().flatMap(Object.keys)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your desired output of `console.log(removedKeys);`
You need to use map and flat insteed flatMap, because flatMap only flattens 1-level deep.

I like to use for to operate with objects since is easy to read.

Like this:

```
const removedKeys  = tempRemovedTimeRanges.map(dObj => {
  const out = [];
  for(const wDay in dObj){
    out.push( dObj[wDay].map( elm=>Object.keys(elm) ) );
  }
  return out;
}).flat(3);
```